# If text begins or ends with these characters, remove characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a jQuery function with a user input text variable `sel`. I display the variable like this:

```
jQuery(this).parent().prev().find('.js-trigger-add-tag-target').text(sel);
```

Works fine.

If the variable **begins** or **ends** with any of these characters:

```
.,?!'"
```

I want to to strip those very characters. For example, if `sel` is:

```
'Hello world, josh's car.,'
```

I want to strip it to:

```
Hello world, josh's car
```

How do I do this in jQuery/javascript? Maybe regex?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with RegEx

```
var regex = /^[.,?!'"]+|[.,?!'"]+$/g;
text = text.replace(regex, '');
```

**RegEx Explanation:**

1. `^`: Starts of the line [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)
2. `$`: End of the line [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)
3. `[.,?!'"]+`: Match any of the characters in the [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[` and `]` that occur one or more times in any order
4. `|`: [OR condition/alteration](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) in the RegEx
5. `g`: Global flag

[**RegEx101 Live Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/dX8xL5/1)

```js
var regex = /^[.,?!'"]+|[.,?!'"]+$/g; // Note that you don't need `m` flag here

var resultEl = document.getElementById('output');
document.getElementById('myInput').addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  resultEl.innerHTML = this.value.replace(regex, '');
}, false);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Type something" />

<div id="output">You'll see output here</div>
```

---

From OP's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35380077/if-text-begins-or-ends-with-these-characters-remove-characters#comment58465170_35380103)

> How do I adjust the regex so that it removes characters if the variable ends with `'s`? For example, if the variable is **John's**, it will become **John**

The RegEx can be modified a bit to match `'s` at the end of the string.

The character class can be make lazy/non-greedy and adding `'s` as optional group at the end of string.

```
/^[.,?!'"]+|[.,?!'"]*?(?:'s)?$/
```

Adding `?` in `[.,?!'"]*?` will make the match [lazy](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#lazy). `(?:)` is [non-capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and adding `?` in `(?:'s)?` will make the `'s` optional.

[**RegEx Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/dX8xL5/2)

Or, as [@Daniel Cheung](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1993909/daniel-cheung) said in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35380077/if-text-begins-or-ends-with-these-characters-remove-characters#comment58465229_35380103), you can also use

```
/^[.,?!'"]+|(?:[.,?!'"]|'s)+$/
```

[**RegEx Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/dX8xL5/3)

**Update:**

To remove spaces `\s` can be added in the character class. Or [`String#trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) can also be used after `replace.

```
/^[.,?!'"\s]+|[.,?!'"\s]+$/
         ^^          ^^
```

[**RegEx Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/dX8xL5/6)

---

As stated in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35380077/if-text-begins-or-ends-with-these-characters-remove-characters/35380103?noredirect=1#comment58655329_35380103) by [@Casimir et Hippolyte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2255089/casimir-et-hippolyte), you can use [`^[\W_]+|[\W_]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/dX8xL5/9) to **remove all the special characters at the beginning and end** of the string.

Comment: **Very** nice! I have a question. How do I adjust the regex so that it removes characters if the variable ends with **'s**? For example, if the variable is **John's**, it will become **John**

Comment: @HenrikPetterson `^[.,?!'"]+|(?:[.,?!'"]|'s)+$`

Comment: This is great. I will accept this answer and bounty it 50 points! Just one final problem. If the text has space at the end or beginning, it doesn't work. Can you adjust the regex to ignore space at beginning or end?

Comment: @HenrikPetterson You just have to add `\s` in the character class. [`^[.,?!'"\s]+|[.,?!'"\s]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/dX8xL5/6)

Comment: You can be more radical using `/^[\W_]+|[\W_]+$/g`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte That can be done if OP want to delete all special characters except `_`. As OP has stated the characters to remove, I think it's better to remove only those characters.

Comment: I understand, note that _ is included (it will be removed too).

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Added that. In case if OP/other users wants to remove all special characters.

Comment: @Tushar is correct, only want to remove the said characters. A lot of unicode characters in my code. Bounty rewarded!

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer a no regex solution simply because the decision "tree" within regex engines is much bigger. and especially because the regexes used for trimming contain query characters which lead to backtracking within the regex engine. such engines often compile the pattern into byte-code, resembling machine instructions. the engine then executes the code, jumping from instruction to instruction. when an instruction fails, it then back-tracks to find another way to match the input. ergo a lot more going on than necessary.

Here is a solution that I personally find more readable and is faster.

```
function trimByChars(string, characters) {
  const first = [...string].findIndex(char => !characters.includes(char));
  const last = [...string].reverse().findIndex(char => !characters.includes(char));
  return string.substring(first, string.length - last);
}
const chars = ["'", '"', ',', '?', '!', '.'];
trimByChars("'Hello world, josh's car.,'", chars);
```